# How to prevent access to a single file based on IP using .htaccess?

Tags: file, ip

All the resources I've read explain how to prevent access to an entire directory based on IP but don't explain how to do this for a single file.

This is what is used to protect a directory:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 123.456.78.910
</Limit>
```

Here only the IP 123.456.78.910 will have access to the directory in which that rule is placed. But the question again is: how to do this for a single file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this :

```
<Files foo.html>
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 123.456.78.910
</Files>
```

By the way, do not use `<Limit GET POST PUT>` to deny access to files, it is a big security hole with most Apache configurations.

Comment: Sorry delroth, but your code just causes an internal server error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's "Files" and not "File". Edited my answer.